# I want to align <div> b with <div> a horizontally, is there a simple way to do it?

Tags: css, html, alignment

When I write   `<div name="a">Foo</div><div name="b">bar</div>`, I want horizontal alignment instead of vertical alignment. How to do it? Is there a simple way to do that? By default, it is vertical alignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the divs to inline-block:

```
.a, .b {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This assumes elements with *classes* of `a` and `b`, not *names* like in the HTML you posted. With this method you can also line up the elements vertically using the `vertical-align` property, i.e. align to the top, middle or bottom:

```
+---+
|   | +---+
| A | | B |
|   | +---+
+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

The default display mode for a div is "block" which includes a line break before and after the div. If you dont want the line breaks you can change the display property to inline which should align them horizontally as long as there is enough width in the parent element to contain both divs.

Display Proprties:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<div style="width:510px; background-color:#ffee88;">
   <div style="display:inline; background-color:#ffeeff;">
      check check 1 2
   </div>
   <div style="display:inline; background-color:#eeffff;">
      hello this time
   </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div style="float:left;" name="a">Foo</div><div style="float:left;" name="b">bar</div>
```

Furthemore, you can set the width of each div:

```
<div style="float:left;width:30%;" name="a">Foo</div><div style="float:left;width:70%;" name="b">bar</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a **SPAN** tag to wrap your Foo and bar elements, or you can set the CSS 'display' attribute for each div to be 'inline-block'.

```
<div name="a" style="display:inline-block">Foo</div>
<div name="b" style="display:inline-block">bar</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These are not demonstrating "vertical alignment", they are [block elements vs. inline elements](http://theopensourcery.com/cssbasics6b.htm).

The simple answer: use **SPAN**, not **DIV**

Comment: What if the content of the divs wasn't just 'foo' and 'bar'? The question is perfectly valid.

Comment: When I replaced DIV with SPAN, I didn't see desirable result.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
<div name="a" style="float:left; width: 100px;">Foo</div>
<div name="b"  style="float:left; width: 100px;">bar</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But there is no space between div a and div b.

Comment: try adding in both CSS "display:inline-block;" and removing the width

Answer (score 0):

You could always do absolute positioning with stylesheets to make your divs line up on the same row. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #logo
        {
            background: #000000;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 250px;
            height: 200px;
        }
        #Banner
        {
            background: #1071A6;
            position: absolute;
            left: 250px;
            top: 0;           
            width: 850px;
            height: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="Banner">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know I can. But it is somewhat complicated.I need a simple yet elegant solution.

Comment: Elegant solution? I'm not sure what you're looking for. Pretty much all of the answers so far given will work to produce what you're asking for. Or is there something more that we're missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
<div id='someSectionOfMyPage'>
   <div name="a">Foo</div>
   <div name="b">bar</div>
</div>
```

Add to your stylesheet:

```
#someSectionOfMyPage div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Check [these examples](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) of css positioning as well.